# Honda Accord 97 won't start without fob button but I lost my fob

Tags: honda, starting, accord, alarm, security

I have an old honda accord that does not start without pressing a button from a makeshift fob. This red light blinks and the emergency lights until i press the fobbutton and then it starts.

I just lost the button, and I can't start the car. Any way to disable it and start the car with just the key?

Thank you

Comment: That in-built security works on so many levels - get a new fob.

Comment: so I can't start it without getting a new fob? can I disable the security and start the car ?

Comment: Well I have never come across one - when you get a new fob : buy two....

Comment: @SolarMike the description suggests that it's an aftermarket immobilizer, in which case disabling it should be quite feasible

Answer (score 2):

So I found a manual inside the car that has some information on how to disable it. Apparently the security system is from a company or brand called VPS.

The solution was to quickly turn the key in the ignition from ACC to Ignition 10 times in a row. The car was then started.

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: This sounds like an aftermarket security system and exact details (make, model of the alarm etc) would help the question and the answer ...